# How to create a new column in output and give values using join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables 'group' and 'prize' where I have id, mem_id, membername in group table and id, prize_memid, prized_memname in prize table.

```
 ***group table***
id    mem_id    membername
1      1          A
2      1          A
3      2          B
4      3          C
5      3          C

***prize table***
id    prize_memid   prized_memname
1       1              A
2       32             yy
3       20             ww
4       2              B
```

I want my result like this using **JOINS** (membership is extra column, that is not in table)

```
***Output***
mem_id   membername  membership
1             A       Prized
2             B       Prized
3             c      Non-Prized
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Group By` on `mem_id` and `member_name`. Do `Left join` starting from `group` table to `prize` table on mem_id. Left join will allow us to consider all the members, whether they have been given a prize or not.
- **Note** that `group` is a [Reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G). You should really considering renaming your table to something else. Otherwise, you will have to use backticks around it.
- Now, use Conditional functions like [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to check if a particular has prize or not (`COUNT(prize_memid)` should be greater than zero, if he has been given a prize atleast once).

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  g.mem_id, 
  g.membername, 
  IF(COUNT(p.prize_memid) > 0, 'Prized', 'Non-Prized') AS membership  
FROM 
  `group` as g 
LEFT JOIN `prize` as p ON p.prize_memid = g.mem_id 
GROUP BY g.mem_id, g.membername
```

Comment: This is what a great answer looks like. Actually teaching the asker with explanations and suggestions for improvement, and not just giving them the answer.